# React dynamic routes based on json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to generate a number of routes based on json data file as follow:

routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './index.jsx';
import Test1 from './test1.jsx';
import Test2 from './test2.jsx';
import TestWrapper from './wrapper.jsx';

import url from './url.json';

var routes = url.url.map(function(el){
   return (<Route key={el} path={el} component={Test1} />);
});

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
        {routes}
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

url.json:

```
{
  "url": [
    "title1",
    "title2",
    "title3",
    "title4"
  ]
}
```

and my test1.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

class Test1 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Test 1</h2>
        <p>hjgjgjh</p>
        <p>{this.props.key}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test1;
```

If I hit my local path/title 1 or title2 or title 3 I should get the following from component "test1":

```
      <div>
        <h2>Test 1</h2>
        <p>hjgjgjh</p>
        <p>{this.props.key}</p>
      </div>
```

but I don't, and I also should have the {this.props.key} printed on screen. I only get whatever is inside the {App} component.

I am not sure if this works correctly:

```
var routes = url.url.map(function(el){
   return (<Route key={el} path={el} component={Test1} />);
});
```

whenI hit my local path/Title1 I don't get any error in the console but the component Test1 doesn't get displayed either.

Comment: What does `App` look like?

Answer (score 0):

See if you're doing something like this in your App component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            App component
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `this.props.children` is where your child component (in your case *Test1*) is located.

Edit: you could also use `React.cloneElement()` if you want to pass extra props.